# Incremental export records from a database table

Tags: database, algorithm, export, backup

For a given table in my system of record (RDBMS), I need to implement a functionality to export the records incrementally. For example, if a user runs an export job which returns x number of records, I want to return a snapshot id back to the user. For the next export job, user will pass that snapshot id to me and using that I should be able to export only the records that have either been modified or added since. Ideally I would like my snapshot ids to be re-usable. In other words, I do not want my snapshot ids to expire, but this is not a hard requirement.

Given that I have LAST_UPDATE_DATE (Timestamp) column in all my tables, what's the best way to solve this problem?

I am not looking for code, tools or commands. I am just looking for the logic of how I should generate this snapshot id and recognize it in subsequent calls to perform an incremental export of records in a given table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps are obviously global, thus a snapshot ID only needs to be a single timestamp. In SQL Server, for example, you can run `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get the current timestamp.

When you want to export, run individual queries on each table to export the rows that have a timestamp between the last exported and the current one. If the timestamp fields are indexed, each of these queries should be quite fast, obviously dependent on the amount of data to be exported.

Assuming you run these exports while other updates on the database can occur, it's important that you only get the current timestamp once, store that as a variable and work with that value (as opposed to using e.g. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` freely), otherwise some data will go missing occasionally.

You may want to consider having a `Deleted` column flag on each table and updating this rather than deleting rows, so you know which rows were 'removed'.

Comment: Thank you, excellent suggestions. Client can preserve the current_timestamp used as ceiling for an export job and that will become the starting point i.e. the lower value for the next run. I also like the idea of no physical deletes otherwise I wouldn't know which records were marked for deletion. This looks simple to implement and will likely become the accepted answer.